# How do we test for elements present using || operator in selenium webdriver

Tags: junit, selenium-webdriver

I am new to webdriver, need some guidance with the following

What I am looking for is:

if (Login || Password) webelement is not present then a message for elements not present will be present

Error what is displayed

```
The operator || is undefined for the argument type(s) org.openqa.selenium.WebElement, org.openqa.selenium.WebElement
```

Using Junit at my end

Comment: I don't see the question in your text. Can you rephrase it a bit? Important stuff: What are you trying to achieve? What did you try? How does it fail?

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want:

```
if(Login.isDisplayed() == false || Password.isDisplayed() == false )
{
   ...
}
```

If not, look at the examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397604/746754), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14156656/how-to-verify-element-present-or-visible-in-selenium-2), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14162927/746754), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646195/how-to-check-if-an-element-is-visible-with-webdriver).

Comment: Hi acarlon,Thanks ... I have 1 more query just for testing navigate to www.irctc.co.in
Click on login without entering the details.U shall get a popup.
Is it possible to identify element of this popup,if yes then how?

Comment: @VS http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14939298/handling-a-popup-window-using-selenium